# how to make a parent child relationship using python Elasticsearch client?

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, parent-child, relationships

I am using python's elasticsearch client to make searchable pdfs. One group of pdf's is called surveys. I would like to make a parent child relationship where the parent consist of the group of pdf's and the child index will be the filenames within the group. However, I keep getting errors. My code is below:

in settings.py:

```
import elasticsearch
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection

ES_CLIENT = Elasticsearch(
    ['http://127.0.0.1:9200/'], #could be 9201,9300,9301
    connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection
)
```

in my command.py:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from django.conf import settings
self.indices_client = settings.ES_CLIENT
 print "create parent"
        self.indices_client.index(
            #   op_type='create',
                id='surveys',
                doc_type='parent',
                body={ "properties": { 'title': {'type': 'string', 'index': 'not_analyzed'}}},
                index="surveys" 
            )
        # create child index file_name with parent index surveys
        # self.indices_client.create(index=child_index)
        print 'create child'
        self.indices_client.index(
            doc_type='child',
            body= upload_models.Survey._meta.es_mapping,
            index=child_index,
            parent='surveys'

        )
        print 'post child'
```

I keep getting this error:

```
raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, u'illegal_argument_exception', u"Can't specify parent if no parent field has been configured")
```

Comment: How did you create your index and how does your mapping look like? Can you update your question with the response you get from `curl -XGET http://127.0.0.1:9200/surveys` ?

Answer (score 0):

During child mapping in:

```
self.indices_client.index(
    doc_type='child',
    body= upload_models.Survey._meta.es_mapping,
    index=child_index,
    parent='surveys'
)
```

parent parameter here is  ID of the parent document, so you can't use it for your purpose, instead try:

```
self.indices_client.index(
    doc_type='child',
    body= {
           doc_type: {
              '_parent': {"type": "surveys"},
              'properties': upload_models.Survey._meta.es_mapping
             }
           }
    index=child_index
)
```

Or try another function - [put_mapping(*args, **kwargs)](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=put_mapping#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.put_mapping):

```
self.indices_client.indices.put_mapping(
    doc_type='child',
    index=child_index,
    body= {
             doc_type: {
               '_parent': {"type": "surveys"},
               'properties': upload_models.Survey._meta.es_mapping
             }
          }
    index=child_index
   )
```